# Xubuntu 2nd monitor

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, xrandr

My second monitor isn't able to get out off the power save mode ( i think ). Everytime I change some monitor changes which should effect the second monitor (VGA1) i turns on for a 1-2 seconds after that it shuts down. Here my xrandr

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3046 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
   680x384        60.0  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected 1680x1050+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      59.9 +   60.0* 
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-1-2 disconnected
VGA-1-2 connected
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI-1-2 disconnected
  1920x1080 (0x103)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x45)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x46)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x47)   36.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
```

I'm not sure which further informations to provide, just ask. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi. It doesn't look like a question, but rather as a bug report. You should report it by opening a terminal and typing "ubuntu-bug xrandr" and following instructions

Comment: hm ok. but the issue came up just after one night of idle and nothing else. "Report belongs to a package which is not installed!"

Comment: just tried another monitor instead, works fine. could be a hardware problem.